# Generating documentation using Sphinx and `sphinx.ext.autosummary` recursively for external `pybind11` module

Tags: python, c++, python-sphinx, pybind11

I am having issues with generating documentation using Sphinx for a python package which contains an external c++ module which uses `pybind11` to generate the Python bindings.

The problem I have is that the compiled `module` contains several `submodules`, yet autosummary with the `:recursive:` option only appears to find the functions and classes of the highest level module. My impression is that the issue resides in that there is no explicit `__init__.py` file for each submodule since the bindings are all packed into one `.so` binary. Is there any way around this?

I am using `Python 3.8` and `Sphinx 3.2.1`. And this is my `index.rst`:

```markdown
.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   Home page <self>
   Examples <examples>
   API reference <_autosummary/mypackage>
```

And this is the `api.rst`:

```markdown
API Reference
=============

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:

   mypackage
```

Comment: Does [`--implicit-namespaces`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-implicit-namespaces) do what you want? C++ also supports namespaces https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#id6

Comment: Is it possible to set this option in the `conf.py` file?

Comment: `implicit_namespaces` is an option to **sphinx-apidoc**. It is not something that can be set in conf.py and it has nothing to do with `autosummary`.